# Schedule camel routes after completion of particular route

Tags: apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

We read a large file into a database (actually, we read Excel to csv and then dump the csv in a DB), when/after this is done i need to dump the results of several SELECT statements into files.

These file are then distributed by mail.

How can i schedule Camel to only start with the SELECTs after the entire file is dumped in the DB table?

Comment: If you are using splitter, you can see if the split is finished by property CamelSplitComplete. But this is an assumption, proving a sample of your code may clear the situation

Comment: Depends on how your code is structured. If you have a single route responsible for dumbing the CSV in a DB then you can use OnCompletition or check the result after the dump and call the route which handles the select part.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several ways to accomplish this. Camel will do this by default, if the routes with the SELECT statements pick up where the route that loaded the data left of.

In the toy example below the first route sets a flag file in one output directory (in lieu of reading a file into a DB), then goes to two endpoints. From these endpoint two routes are started that copy a file to two different output directories.

The *.multicast()* line can be left out, it's not clear to me when it is neccessary.

```
public class DivergentRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    final String FLAG_URI = "file:data/output?doneFileName=${file:name}.flag";
    final String OUTPUT = "file:data/output";
    final String OUTPUT2 = "file:data/output2";

    final String REPORT1 = "direct:one";
    final String REPORT2 = "direct:two";

    final Route2IsScheduled isScheduled = new Route2IsScheduled();

    from("file:data/input")
    .to("log:?level=INFO&showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
     .to(FLAG_URI)
     .multicast()
     .to(REPORT1, REPORT2);

    from(REPORT1)
        .to(OUTPUT);

    from(REPORT2)
        .choice()
            .when(isScheduled)
                .to(OUTPUT2)
            .otherwise()
                .stop()
            .end();
    }
}
```

However, when reading the file into a DB and outputting the results of the SELECT statements have different schedules, this code gets ugly. Say a Data Warehouse is updated daily but some report is only required monthly, then the corresponding route has to check if it's scheduled. This happend with *isSchduled* in the example.

I have similar requirements, so in the end i choose to schedule my routes via Quartz individually. The route that stores the data is scheduled 1 hour earlier than the routes that read the data. The latter have to check if the data is up to date.